# Naming conventions for destructive vs. non-destructive methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, syntax, methods

Are there any good naming conventions for destructive vs. non-destructive methods in Javascript? In ruby there's the ! after method, but JS syntax doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 6):

No, I've never come across any.

For instance, the [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method is destructive where as [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) isn't. You wouldn't know which was which unless you consulted the documentation.

Comment: True, at least there's non in the standard library. I guess what i'm wondering is if there are any libraries that has some convention; something like adding 'M' in the end of every method that modifies the original object.

Comment: @JussiR: Again, I've not come across any, and I've seen my fair share.